# How to skip words under a certain length when counting frequency

Tags: python

I'm making a program that takes three poems from the internet and, using Python, parsing the HTML and finding out things like word count and noun phrase variety.
In my function def(frequency_counter), I'm trying to count the most frequent words in the three poems, and I'm trying to only count the words over a length of 3 (so words like "a" and "the" are not included), but I think I've made a mistake in my list comprehension (item = [item for item in total_library if len(item) >= 3]). I've included my imports and the two previous functions for context, but the trouble I'm having is just in the last small function. Any tips on how my list comprehension should look?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
from textblob import TextBlob
from collections import Counter


def get_text(*args):
    text_list =[]
    total_list=[]
    for link in args:
        url = link
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
        title = soup.find('title') #finds title 
        #print(title)
        text = html2text.html2text(soup.prettify())
        lines = text.split("\n")
        for word in lines: #for every item in text
            text_tuple = [title, word] #makes tuple
            text_list.append(text_tuple) #append tuple to empty list
           # print(text_list)
        for item in text_list:  
            title_dictionary = {"title": title, "text": item[1]}
            total_list.append(title_dictionary)
    #print(total_list)
    return total_list

def big_index(text_list):
    each_text = []
    for entry in text_list: #for every entry in text_list, creates smaller 

    total_text = ""
    for x in each_text:
        y = str(x)
        total_text = total_text + y
    total_library = total_text.split("text title:")
    #print(total_text)
    return total_library
    #problem I ran into here: this gives me the books twice, not once. I plan
    #to solve this by taking any counts I get in the future functions and 
    #dividing them by two. Ugly, but I can't figure out where the problem is. 

def frequency_counter(total_library):
    words = []
    for item in total_library:
        item = [item for item in total_library if len(item) >= 3]
        blob1 = TextBlob(item)
        count = blob1.word_counts
        frequency = Counter(count).most_common(10) #10 most common words
        words.append(frequency)
    print(words) 
    return words
```

Comment: If you don't want words like `the` to be a list list comprehension should be `item = [item for item in total_library if len(item) > 3]`

Comment: Instead of testing length you should probably be doing `word not in stop_words` where `stop_words` is a set like http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords

Comment: And you definitely should not do it in a cycle

Comment: I should also say: the error I get when I run this is TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'list'>.

Comment: update you error message, please

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov Can you clarify what you mean by "in a cycle"?

Answer (score 1):

```
def frequency_counter(total_library):
    words = []
    items = [item1 for item1 in total_library if len(item1) > 3]
    for item in items:
        blob1 = TextBlob(item)
        count = blob1.word_counts
        frequency = Counter(count).most_common(10) #10 most common words
        words.append(frequency)
    print(words) 
    return words
```

Comment: Hmm. For some reason your answer, though it makes sense to me, continues to give me the most frequent words of any length, including words like "a" and "of".

Comment: is your character encoding UTF-8 ?

Comment: I don't really know what that means, sorry. I've googled it but it's mostly gibberish to me, I'm just a beginner. I know some situations when you have to use it but I've never known why.

Comment: if your "total_library" contain only english words ?

Comment: add this line to at the top of your .py file `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`